# Logging Google SketchUp timestamp events

Tags: ruby, logging, file-io, sketchup

I'd like any ideas you have for a problem we're looking to solve via SketchUp ( as a university research project).

- For a usability study, we want create a **timestamped** log all the SketchUp tool changing events into a .XML, CSV, or txt file during a modeling task given to a user.
  e.g. while drawing a Cylinder, all events like- 1. selecting a circle, 2. selecting Push/Pull etc. need to be logged to a text based file.

Please pingback any neat ideas you have for doing such a plugin.

Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Does SketchUp have an API that will allow you to be notified of these events?  If so could you kindly link to it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add an `Observer Class` to your project, then utilize `Time.now` and Ruby's built-in File IO to create and/or write to your text/log file.

[Ruby File Class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html)

[ToolsObserver](http://code.google.com/apis/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/toolsobserver.html)

[AppObserver](http://code.google.com/apis/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/appobserver.html)